# What exceptions can be thrown when downloading a file?

Tags: android, exception, download

In my app I have a facility to download reference data updates.  The user can modify base url in a `PreferenceActivity` - and then I append the actual file name to the base URL.  When I attempt to download the file, an exception may be thrown if something went wrong.  I'd like to present the user with the most appropriate error message rather than simply "error occurred".  To do this, I want to catch individual exception and format messages accordingly.  So, what exceptions can be thrown when downloading a file?  For the reference, here's my downloading code (simplified):

```
int msgId;
try {
    String url = props.getProperty(Constants.SETTINGS_REFDATA_SOURCE);
    if(!url.endsWith("/")) {
        url += "/";
    }

    url += Constants.UPDATE_CUSTOMER_FILE;
    CSVReader in = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

    ...//read and parse file here
}
catch(MalformedURLException e) {
   msgId = R.string.error_invalid_base_url;
}
catch(UnknownHostException e) {
   msgId = R.string.error_unknown_host;
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
   msgId = R.string.error_file_not_found;
}
catch(IOException e) {
   msgId = R.string.error_reading_data;
}
catch(MyParseException e) {
   msgId = R.string.error_invalid_file_format;
}
catch(Exception e) {
   msgId = R.string.error_other_error;
}
finally {
    try { in.close(); } catch(Exception e2) {}
}

// then I display AlertDialog using msgId as the message
```

As you can see, I'm already catching several exception - some that I know can be thrown, some that I encountered in testing.  What other exceptions do I need to cater for? Note that the amount of data being download is quite small (at most 15-20 Kb) so things like `OutOfMemoryError` shouldn't be applicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the `ConnectException` due to connection timeout or connection refused (`HTTP 403`)

//edit: I just read, that "Most applications *should not* catch the ConnectException; it is more robust to catch the superclass [SocketException](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/SocketException.html)."

Furthermore you could test if there is an active Internet connection:

```
private boolean checkCon() {
    ConnectivityManager conMgr =  (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if ( conMgr.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED 
        &&  conMgr.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I already test whether there's a connection using connectivity manager, before I start the whole download process, so that's covered.  I'll add SocketException , thanks.